# How to use the NEW keyword when a field is the concatenation of multiple columns?

Tags: postgresql

This is a mockup of the basic table that I want to create a trigger for:

---

| customer_id_name | month_yr | total_amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jane Doe | May 2021 | 9.98 |
| John Smith | May 2021 | 9.97 |
| Frank Castle | Apr 2021 | 8.21 |

---

Here is the code for this table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS payment_detail AS
SELECT customer.customer_id || '--' || customer.first_name || ' ' || customer.last_name AS customer_id_name,
   to_char(payment_date, 'Mon YYYY') AS month_yr,
   SUM(payment.amount) AS total_amount
FROM payment
INNER JOIN customer ON payment.customer_id = customer.customer_id
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY
   MAX(date_trunc('year', payment_date)) DESC,
   MAX(date_trunc('month', payment_date)) DESC,
   MAX(amount) DESC;
```

Note that the column, `customer_id_name`, is a concatenation of three columns. This is a column that I'd need to update in a trigger function. How do you handle this in a trigger function when you need to use the NEW keyword? Do you not need to use subqueries? That's where I'm stuck.

Here's my trigger function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_payment_detail()
   RETURNS TRIGGER LANGUAGE PLPGSQL AS
$$
BEGIN
   UPDATE payment_detail SET
   customer_id_name = (NEW.customer_id || '--' NEW.first_name || ' ' || NEW.last_name),
   month_yr = to_char(NEW.payment_date, 'Mon YYYY'),
   total_amount = (SUM(NEW.payment.amount))
FROM
   customer
WHERE
   customer.customer_id = NEW.customer_id;
END;
$$

CREATE TRIGGER update_payment_detail
   AFTER UPDATE
   ON payment
   FOR EACH ROW
   EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_payment_detail();
```

When I run an UPDATE on the `payment` table:

```
UPDATE payment
SET amount = 4.00
WHERE payment_id = 32034 AND customer_id = 60;
```

I get the following error:

ERROR: record "new" has no field "first_name"

LINE 10: (NEW.customer.customer_id || '--' || NEW.customer.first_name...

So the error points to the WHERE clause in the trigger, specifically the statement after the `=` sign. I think it has something to do with me not using the NEW keyword properly, and I think the concatenation operator is where there must be special considerations, but my Google-Fu has failed me on this one. How could this be resolved?

Comment: For added clarity: What attributes does `customer` have? Also, what attribute(s) is the primary key in that table? How come you need to concatenate attributes?

Comment: **If** `customer_id` is your primary key in `customer`, then all you need to do is have: `WHERE customer_id = NEW.customer_id`

Comment: @Chrimle that sure fixed it. I also see now that I didn't need to specify the ```customer``` table name in the ```SET customer_id_name = (NEW.customer.customer_id ...``` code, so I fixed that. So now my ```UPDATE``` code looks like this:

```UPDATE payment detail SET
customer_id_name = (NEW.customer_ID || '--' || NEW.first_name || ' ' || NEW.last_name)
...
```

But now I get an error saying that "record "new" has no field "first_name"...

Comment: Yeah, (I am completely guessing now) but I assume NEW **does** have `customer_id`. If so, you don't need to check their `first_name` or their `last_name`. That's the whole point of `id`s, they uniquely identify customers. While on the other hand, their name is certainly not. There are many people with the same name, that's why you needed an `id` to begin with. To differentiate between two "John Anderson"s. So, you can get rid of `NEW.first_name` too. (Well, you **have** to get rid of it, as that reference is not valid)

Comment: However, if you ever wanted to check if the name was the same, you would have to `SELECT` from all the customers, `WHERE` the id is the same. Then, you have access to their name. So then, you could check if their name is longer than 5 characters, or begins with a `D` or whatever it is.

Comment: Another thing that I noticed: What is `customer_id_name`? The table `payments` should have a `customer_id` too. You should NOT concatenate their name into the id. What if they change their name?

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out the corrections with the help of @Chrimle:

The trigger function should look like this instead:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_payment_detail()
   RETURNS TRIGGER LANGUAGE PLPGSQL AS
$$
BEGIN
   UPDATE payment_detail SET
   customer_id_name = (NEW.customer_id || '--' first_name || ' ' || last_name),
   month_yr = to_char(NEW.payment_date, 'Mon YYYY'),
   total_amount = (SUM(NEW.amount))
FROM
   customer, payment
WHERE
   customer.customer_id = NEW.customer_id;
END;
$$

CREATE TRIGGER update_payment_detail
   AFTER UPDATE
   ON payment
   FOR EACH ROW
```